# Creating a new column with conditions in addition to the row value of the new column

Tags: r, dplyr, case, lag, mutated

Any ideas on how to create a new column B using the values of column A,
while using the value of the row above of the new created colum B?

The value of B should be corresponding to:

```
A0 = value of the row above.
A1 = 1.
A2 = value of the row above + 1.
```

Current dataframe + desired outcome

```
                
Dataframe           Desired outcome  
A                   A   B
1                   1   1
0                   0   1
2                   2   2
0                   0   2
2                   2   3
0                   0   3
2                   2   4
0                   0   4
2                   2   5
0                   0   5
2                   2   6
0                   0   6
1                   1   1
0                   0   1
1                   1   1
0                   0   1
2                   2   2
0                   0   2
2                   2   3
0                   0   3
1                   1   1
0                   0   1
2                   2   2
0                   0   2


Data Frame
A <- c(1,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,2,0,2,0,1,0,2,0)
Bdesiredoutcome <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2)
df = data.frame(A,Bdesiredoutcome)
```

I tried using `dpylr, mutate(), case_when()` and `lag()` but keep running into errors. Due to using the `lag()` function. When using `lag(A)` the desired outcome cannot be generated.
Any idea's on how to solve this problem?

```
df <- df %>%
          mutate(B = case_when((A == 0) ~ lag(B), 
                               (A == 1) ~ 1,
                               (A == 2) ~ (lag(B)+1)
    ))

Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"
In addition: Warning message:
```

Comment: The error is because you didn't have a `B` column, but just `Bdesired` i.e. if you do ` mutate(B = Bdesired, B= case_when((A == 0) ~ lag(B), ...` it should work

Comment: Thanks for the quick anser, sadly Bdesired is the desired outcome and not availible for the whole data. Therefore i am try to calculate B using only A. The outcome form B should be the same as Bdesired. I've edited the post to make it clear, thanks =)

Comment: Ok, but your code shows `lag(B)` when it doesn't exist at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a grouping column with `cumsum` and then create the 'B' column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(A == 1)) %>% 
   mutate(B = cumsum(A != 0)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp) %>%
   as.data.frame
```

-output

```
   A Bdesired B
1  1        1 1
2  0        1 1
3  2        2 2
4  0        2 2
5  2        3 3
6  0        3 3
7  2        4 4
8  0        4 4
9  2        5 5
10 0        5 5
11 2        6 6
12 0        6 6
13 1        1 1
14 0        1 1
15 1        1 1
16 0        1 1
17 2        2 2
18 0        2 2
19 2        3 3
20 0        3 3
21 1        1 1
22 0        1 1
23 2        2 2
24 0        2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

On your original question I got the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df$date <-dmy(df$date)


df <- df %>% 
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(daysbetween = replace_na(date - lag(date),0),
         ind = 1,
         NewA= case_when (daysbetween < 7 ~ 0, daysbetween > 7 ~ 1),
         NewB= case_when (daysbetween < 85 ~ 0, daysbetween > 85 ~ 1),
         A =   case_when (1 + cumsum(ind*NewA) <= 6 ~ 1 + cumsum(ind*NewA),
                          1 + cumsum(ind*NewA) > 6 ~ 1 + cumsum(ind*NewA) - 6),
         B =  1 + cumsum(ind*NewB))%>%
  select(id, date, A, B)
```

It only works if the reset for A is at 6. I used `cumsum()` as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am sorry for simplifying the question. I througt i would be easyer. Didn’t know you were working on it. Thanks for the imput! I can use this to do another variabel column with new data (:!